# Microsoft Expression Web 4 javascript auto completion

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, microsoft-expression-web

I am using Microsoft Expression Web 4, and I am doing some JavaScript. However, when I type a bracket or a curved bracket, I don't see Microsoft Expression Web putting a closing bracket after it (like other IDEs like Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc. will do).

***Question:*** Does Microsoft Expression Web 4 support syntax auto-completion for javascript? If yes, then how do I use it?

Comment: I haven't used expression web 4 myself, but it might be helpful. [Intellisense Options in Microsoft Expression Web 3](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=412) (if you haven't already looked in the article)

Comment: @cupid Alright, I guess that is good enough. You can post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you.
I haven't used expression web 4 myself, but it might be helpful. [Intellisense Options in Microsoft Expression Web 3](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=412) (if you haven't already looked in the article)